# What's the point of ref-qualified member functions in `std::optional::value`

Tags: c++, stdoptional, ref-qualifier

These are the signatures, according to Cppreference:

```cpp
constexpr T& value() &;
constexpr const T& value() const &;

constexpr T&& value() &&;
constexpr const T&& value() const &&;
```

What's the point of using `&/const&` and `&&/const&&`?
Especially, I don't understand the point of having a `const&&` overload. `const` objects shouldn't be moved, so why would we have this?

Comment: because it's a generic template it can hold any type with any properties. So for optimizations purposes you need a way move the value out of a temporary. What exactly is your doubt?

Comment: My exact doubt is why we need an overload for `const&&`.

Comment: you can't know what the T object does. Because you are in a generic context you need to preserve the reference type. For instance T might have  an `foo() const &&` method overload. If you don't have `optional<T>value() const&&` overload the user loses the ability to use the `T::foo() const &&` overload.

Comment: But in that case `const&` would be the preferred function, if `const&&` overload didn't exist in the first place, or am I missing your point?

Comment: I've written a full answer. Hope it clarifies what I mean.

Comment: From a language design perspective, I would pose two counter-questions. 1) Is there any harm (other than to your understanding) caused by having all four forms? 2) Suppose the `const&&` form was omitted; can you guarantee that no one will ever come up with a scenario where this is problematic? (In general, it is difficult to prove the non-existence of a counterexample.)

Comment: @JaMiT Well, 1) probably not, and 2) surely not. Good counter questions. However they don't answer the original question I guess... :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's all about being in a generic template context. The standard library here needs to support all the possible scenarios (you an imagine and the ones you can't imagine) because I assure you some C++ project somewhere does use it.

So if you have a user defined type `X` as follows:

```
struct X
{
    void foo() &;          // 1
    void foo() const &;    // 2

    void foo() &&;         // 3
    void foo() const &&;   // 4
};
```

where `foo` is optimized for const temporary (`foo (4)`) vs const non-temporary (`foo (2)`) the standard library needs to support that with `std::optional`.

If `std::optinal` would be missing the `constexpr const T&& value() const &&;` when the user has a `std::optional<X> const &&` (it can be in a generic template context) and tries to call `foo` on it the `foo (2)` would be called instead of  `foo (4)`.

What I mean by calling `foo` here:

```
const std::optional<X> && get_const_xvalue();
get_const_xvalue().get()foo();

// or in a generic template:

template <class Opt>
void bar(Opt&& o)
{
    std::forward<Opt>(o).get().foo();
}

// where `o` can be of type `std::optional<X> const &&`
```

There is a worst scenario. Imagine a user type type `Y` like so:

```
struct X
{
    void foo() &       = delete;  // 1
    void foo() const & = delete;  // 2

    void foo() &&;                // 3
    void foo() const &&;          // 4
};
```

In this case trying to access `foo` on a const temporary would result in a compiler error instead of calling the expected `foo 4` overload.

Comment: I see, I thought we could just `std::move(get_const_temp().foo())` to call our foo's `const T&&` overload (so in this case `std::optional::value` overload with const T&& could be `=delete`), but in generic code that would be annoying.
Thanks. Really appreciated!

Comment: You are welcome. Granted, const temporaries are not very useful. But as a library writter you never know what crazy pattern someone invents that uses that.